# Isolate UART Signal Pins

Tags: pic, modem

I'm working with an embedded cell modem that will be living on a battery, hopefully for a long period.  It only wakes up and sends data occasionally.  To that end, my plan is to cut power to it when it's not needed to conserve power.  However, I've noticed that if I put a MOSFET-based switch on the power supply to the modem, that seems to successfully shut it down, but there ends up being significant current leakage on the DIN and DOUT pins of the modem (which are connected to pins on the processor, of course).

I'm hoping to add something so that I can send a high signal from a third pin of my processor, which would then allow signals to pass between the processor and the DIN and DOUT pins of the modem, but if hold that pin low, it will isolate DIN and DOUT so that no current can flow.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just set the microprocessor pins to input mode?

Comment: ... and insure there are no pullups, perhaps even have a weak pulldown as a keeper.  For the MCU to module line, you might as well just drive it low.

Comment: To fix the issue, just drive DIN to the modem low before you cut the power to the modem. I can explain longer if you need a better explanation but that simple change will prevent the leakage.

Comment: To both immibis and Vince Patron, no.  I see that current leakage regardless of whether I set the pins on the PIC low, high, or leave them open.

Comment: If you turn the power supply off, and set the PIC pins low, then all of the modem's pins are at ground, so *where can the current be coming from*?

Comment: I felt the same way!  See below; it looks like leaving the UART enabled on the PIC overrides my trying to set those pins low manually.  Disabling UART, then holding the pins low, and then shutting down the modem seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TXD of a UART is normally high, in idle.

Therefore if your modem is unpowered, since the ground is still connected, some current will flow from the TXD pin to the modem.

In fact, the IC of the modem will have input protection diodes, which clamp to its V<sub>DD</sub> any voltage higher than that. This could be also potentially dangerous, due to latch-up (and furthermore your TXD pin will be powering all the modem circuitry connected to its V<sub>DD</sub> rail...).

**My suggestion is:**

Put a weak pull-down in the RXD line and:

a) When you need to turn off:

- Disable the UART.
- Put the TXD as output low (I just checked a random PIC18, and I don't see they have a pull-down feature).
- Turn off the modem.

b) When you need to turn on the modem:

- Turn on the modem.
- Enable UART.

In theory, by outputting a low-TXD, while the modem is enabled, you might have some troubles. In fact a low-TXD value is a start condition. But your MCU will be fast enough to complete all the step in few microseconds. Therefore:

- The steps will be faster than the modem initialization time at startup.
- They will likely be faster than a "bit" time too. Therefore that spurious "0" will be just ignored.
- Still, stop bit will be missing, so the modem's UART should ignore any data.

Comment: Seems promising.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Explicitly shutting off UART seems to have done the job.  Thanks!